# Matte box for my S20 Ultra?

Tags: lighting, photography-basics, accessories, lighting-basics, natural-lighting

I'm shooting products in daylight for a business project. I noticed sometimes there is a haze from the sun and cupping my hand in front of the lens eliminates it significantly.

Are there any options for matte boxes or can I DIY?

-

I have the tripod mount pictured. It's great. Aluminium CNC and has a foot on the top as well as 4 threaded holes for accessories.

You can only see one in the photo but each side has one on the top and bottom.

[image: My tripod mount]

Answer (score 2):

You just need a hotshoe (foot slot) mounted flag. They are available for about $30 (Glide Gear LS100); but yo could probably DIY something smaller/simpler for less.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the appropriate lens hood for the lens you're using. That will handle a fair amount of the undesired light. As mentioned in another answer, adding flags, whether camera mounted, or tripod mounted, or even standalone, can handle much of what's left. On top of that, using a room that has no windows, and then whatever sorts of lights you actually want, would allow you to completely control the lighting...

Comment: The S20 Ultra seems to be a Samsung smartphone. The picture of the smartphone bracket supports that interpretation (I have one of similar design and they are very useful). I don’t think there is a lens hood for the S20 Ultra.